# Why does the Launcher App show First Activity, when the other app finished?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I created a launcher app that contains two activities, `MainActivity` and `DrawerActivity`.
I start the other app (Music App) from `DrawerActivity`.

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.music");   
startActivity(intent);
```

When I closed the music app.
I have a question. The launcher shows the page `MainActivity` first (very fast), then page `DrawerActivity`, but doesn't call `onCreate` or `onResume` (`MainActivity`).

Launcher `AndroidManiestfest.xml`

```
<activity
            android:name=".main.MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">

            <intent-filter android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

<activity
            android:name=".drawer.DrawerActivity"
            android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Comment: pls share ur MainActivity java code also?

Comment: [MainActivity](https://gist.github.com/fccaikai/d7dd0080b15e304aabc9d6fe492fa708)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with your code line:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're prioritizing reading the intent from the first Activity with this line.

Try removing it and see if it still occurs?